# Google cloud + bitnami + FTP how I can find file on my GC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I can't find were bitnami place wordpress files on Google Cloud, any one can give piece of advice
1. How can I correct setup FTP connection to Google Cloud + Bitnami ?
2.

Comment: The location depends on the Bitnami package that you installed. Consult the documentation. FTP is very insecure. Use SSH / SCP / SFTP instead which is already setup on your Google Compute VM.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here. The Bitnami files are inside the /opt/bitnami directory. You can find all the necessary files to run the application there. For example, Apache files are inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2 folder and the WordPress files ones are inside the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs directory. You will be able to check the infrastructure by clicking [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/understand-directory-structure/).

As @john-hanley mentioned, use SSH or SFTP protocols to access into the WordPress files. You will need to add your SSH key to the instance as metadata, then connect to the instance using a client in your computer. You will learn more about that [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/administration/upload-files/).